# Nvidia drivers interfering with computer booting

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, nvidia

I've been dealing with this problem on and off for about a month, and I've been spending quite some time on the side trying to fix it. I think it's now time to ask for help.

So, when I boot my laptop, one of 3 things can happen.

1. The computer boots fine, no problem.
2. The computer boots and I get a message saying that the computer is running in low graphics mode. If I select the option to try running the default mode, then it runs fine.
3. The computer doesn't boot at all. The booting process stops at `Loading initial ramdisk...`.

From what I've researched, it seems like Nvidia drivers might be causing this problem. I am currently running driver 390.12, but I've tried pretty much all the ones in the `graphics-drivers` ppa, and the problem persisted.

It is possible for me to force the laptop to boot by adding the line `acpi=off` in the GRUB menu. This, however, forces the laptop to run with the integrated Intel graphics card, which is not ideal.

Here are my specs:

- Computer: Lenovo Thinkpad P50
- Graphics card: Nvidia Quadro M1000M (GM107GLM)
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I don't think it matters that much, but I'm also dual booting with windows 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if I should add any other information. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is helpful to anyone having similar problems, the issue was solved by updating the BIOS with the [latest](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds106108) found on Lenovo's website. Lenovo seemed to only offer those for Windows, so I needed to update on the Windows side. Everything is back to normal now!